# Xampp not working suddenly

Tags: apache

my xampp doesn't seem to work after I tinkered around a bit with the httpd.conf file. This is a part my error log (It only shows the errors up till 08:44 whereas it was 16:19 when I tried last).

```
[Tue Jul 07 08:44:32.836389 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3880:tid 376] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jul 07 08:44:32.883264 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3880:tid 376] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 07 08:44:32.883264 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3880:tid 376] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Tue Jul 07 08:44:32.883264 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3880:tid 376] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Jul 07 08:44:32.883264 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3880:tid 376] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7348
[Tue Jul 07 08:44:33.477024 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7348:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jul 07 08:44:33.680150 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 7348:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jul 07 08:44:33.727025 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7348:tid 384] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

My console looks like this

```
4:13:22 PM  [main]  Initializing Control Panel
4:13:22 PM  [main]  Windows Version: Windows 8  64-bit
4:13:22 PM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 5.6.8
4:13:22 PM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
4:13:22 PM  [main]  You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
4:13:22 PM  [main]  most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
4:13:22 PM  [main]  there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
4:13:22 PM  [main]  about running this application with administrator rights!
4:13:22 PM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
4:13:22 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
4:13:23 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
4:13:23 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
4:13:23 PM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
4:13:23 PM  [Apache]    Port 135 in use by "C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k RPCSS" with PID 840!
4:13:23 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
4:13:23 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
4:13:23 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
4:13:23 PM  [main]  The FileZilla module is disabled
4:13:23 PM  [main]  The Mercury module is disabled
4:13:23 PM  [main]  The Tomcat module is disabled
4:13:23 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
4:13:23 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
4:13:24 PM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
4:13:24 PM  [Apache]    Port 135 in use by "C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k RPCSS" with PID 840!
4:13:24 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
4:13:24 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
4:13:24 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
4:13:24 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
4:15:58 PM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
4:15:58 PM  [Apache]    Port 135 in use by "C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k RPCSS" with PID 840!
4:15:58 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
4:15:58 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
4:15:58 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
4:15:58 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
4:15:58 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
4:15:59 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
4:15:59 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
4:15:59 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:15:59 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:15:59 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:15:59 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:15:59 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
4:15:59 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
4:16:06 PM  [main]  Executing "services.msc"
4:16:17 PM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
4:16:17 PM  [Apache]    Port 135 in use by "C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k RPCSS" with PID 840!
4:16:17 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
4:16:17 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
4:16:17 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
4:16:17 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
4:16:17 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
4:16:18 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
4:16:18 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
4:16:18 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:16:18 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:16:18 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:16:18 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:16:18 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
4:16:18 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Finally, this is my httpd-conf file:

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/foo.log"
# with ServerRoot set to "C:/xampp/apache" will be interpreted by the
# server as "C:/xampp/apache/logs/foo.log".
#
# NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
# instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
# If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which Apache.exe is located
# will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
# an explicit drive letter in absolute paths, however, to avoid
# confusion.
#

# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in the server process
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum  number of requests a server process serves
ThreadsPerChild 250
MaxRequestsPerChild  0

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
# at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
# httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses (0.0.0.0)
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 8888

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
#LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so # don't load because of mod_autoindex_color.so
#LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

LoadModule autoindex_color_module modules/mod_autoindex_color.so
#LoadModule mysql_auth_module modules/mod_auth_mysql.so
#LoadModule auth_remote_module modules/mod_auth_remote.so
#LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so
#LoadModule log_sql_module modules/mod_log_sql.so
#LoadModule log_sql_mysql_module modules/mod_log_sql_mysql.so
#<IfModule ssl_module>
#    LoadModule log_sql_ssl_module modules/mod_log_sql_ssl.so
#</IfModule>
#LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
#LoadModule xmlns_module modules/mod_xmlns.so
#LoadModule proxy_xml_module modules/mod_proxy_xml.so
#LoadModule bw_module modules/mod_bw.so

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin bderchak2@verizon.net

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName rangerxlt8.homelinux.net:1080

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php4 index.php3 index.cgi index.pl index.html index.htm index.shtml index.phtml
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog logs/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    CustomLog logs/access.log common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    #CustomLog logs/access.log combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

#
# "C:/xampp/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

# 
# Apache parses all CGI scripts for the shebang line by default.
# This comment line, the first line of the script, consists of the symbols
# pound (#) and exclamation (!) followed by the path of the program that 
# can execute this specific script.  For a perl script, with perl.exe in
# the C:\Program Files\Perl directory, the shebang line should be:

   #!c:/program files/perl/perl

# Note you _must_not_ indent the actual shebang line, and it must be the
# first line of the file.  Of course, CGI processing must be enabled by 
# the appropriate ScriptAlias or Options ExecCGI directives for the files 
# or directory in question.
#
# However, Apache on Windows allows either the Unix behavior above, or can
# use the Registry to match files by extention.  The command to execute 
# a file of this type is retrieved from the registry by the same method as 
# the Windows Explorer would use to handle double-clicking on a file.
# These script actions can be configured from the Windows Explorer View menu, 
# 'Folder Options', and reviewing the 'File Types' tab.  Clicking the Edit
# button allows you to modify the Actions, of which Apache 1.3 attempts to
# perform the 'Open' Action, and failing that it will try the shebang line.
# This behavior is subject to change in Apache release 2.0.
#
# Each mechanism has it's own specific security weaknesses, from the means
# to run a program you didn't intend the website owner to invoke, and the
# best method is a matter of great debate.
#
# To enable the this Windows specific behavior (and therefore -disable- the
# equivilant Unix behavior), uncomment the following directive:
#
#ScriptInterpreterSource registry
#
# The directive above can be placed in individual <Directory> blocks or the
# .htaccess file, with either the 'registry' (Windows behavior) or 'script' 
# (Unix behavior) option, and will override this server default option.
#

#
# DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For files that include their own HTTP headers:
    #AddHandler send-as-is asis

    # For server-parsed imagemap files:
    #AddHandler imap-file map

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
   AddType text/html .shtml
   AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
#MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
#
EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# XAMPP specific settings
Include conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
# Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

Please help me figure this out. It was working fine yesterday.

Comment: I found out that one of the problems, the only one I could find, was that itunes was using port 135, so I stopped that process and restarted apache (well, started because it was running in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the port (8888) Apache is trying to bind to is free; you may have to change it in `httpd.conf`. There may be a process running that still has the port locked to it, so you may want to check running processes and kill any which may be causing an issue.

This can happen if a process doesn't exit properly and any subsidiary processes may remain running.

The error log won't start getting populated until Apache successfully starts.

Comment: I'm constantly getting that error, though I found a few listening ports using `netstat -a -b`. BTW: Does showing my file give up security in any way?

Comment: @ytpillai Your `httpd.conf` file? If so then not really if it's for a local environment that isn't accessible from the internet. It's also worth a try adding the line: `Listen 127.0.0.1:8888` in place of `Listen 8888` to see if that works for you since then it'll only try to bind to localhost rather than all available IP's.

Comment: OK thanks just making sure and I'll try that right now

Comment: I keep getting an error that says
`Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
6:58:56 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
6:58:56 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
6:58:56 PM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
6:58:56 PM  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
6:58:56 PM  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
6:58:56 PM  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
`It says nothing about ports being not available, that's a different error (in the console posted)

Comment: Please ignore the time["Apache"] thing

Comment: @ytpillai if you run `apachectl configtest` from the console what is the output?

Comment: I don't have that program in my PATH and I can't find it in the xampp folder. I get that apachectl is not recognized

Comment: @ytpillai Have a look in the Windows event log in administrative tools and see if it's logging any more detailed errors there. It's probably in the Application logs.

Comment: No xampp in there, what am I looking for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82651/discussion-between-daniel-waghorn-and-ytpillai).